# Integrate firebase notificaiton in nest js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nestjs

I am trying to create fcm API using nest js which I am using in a flutter. I am new to Nest js and I have implemented the code using [this](https://dev.to/aswinsanakan/how-to-integrate-firebase-in-nestjs-5gl9).
There is no error in my code but I don't receive the notification on my phone
Below is my service file in which I have implemented the push notification

```
 async sendMessageToUser(registrationToken) {
     
      var message = {
        android: {
        ttl: 3600 * 1000, // 1 hour in milliseconds
  
        data: {
        title: "hiii",
        body: "hello",
       
        }
        
         },
        apns: {
        headers: {
        'apns-priority': '10'
        },
        payload: {
        "aps": {
        "alert": {
        "body": "hii",
        "title": "hello"
        },
        "sound": "dafault",
        
        }
        }
        },
        token: registrationToken
        };
      
      
    
      
      // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
      // registration token with the provided options.
      try{
        Logger.log("FIrst try catch");
        await admin.messaging().send(message);
        try {
          Logger.log("second try catch");
          
        } catch (error) {
          Logger.error(error);
        }
      }catch (error) {
        Logger.error(error);
      }
     
     
  }
```

main.ts file

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import admin, { ServiceAccount } from 'firebase-admin';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    
  
  // Set the config options
  const adminConfig: ServiceAccount = {
    "projectId":"my firebase projetId", 
    "privateKey": "private key".replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    "clientEmail": "firebase client email",
  };
  // Initialize the firebase admin app
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(adminConfig),
    databaseURL: "db url",
  });

  app.enableCors();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

can someone tell me what's wrong with my code why I didn't receive the notification on my phone?

Comment: Did you tried printing the results of admin.messaging().send()?

Answer (score 2):

Create a Module to initialize Firebase App firebase.module.ts

```
import {ApiConfigService} from '@config/config.service'
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as adminConfig from 'firebase-creds.json'

@Module({})
export class FirebaseModule {
  constructor(configService: ApiConfigService) {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(adminConfig),
      databaseURL: "db URL",
    })
  }
}
```

And then use it this way app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    FirebaseModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

After that, you are able to use it in any service that you want as admin.messaging().sendtodevice as you do on your code